# Where can I ask questions about tools like Atlassian Jira?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What, if any, Stack Exchange site could I ask a simple question about Jira?
For instance:

> We are using Jira Agile and we have a board with columns:
>
> - Ideas
> - Next Up
> - On Hold
> - In Progress
> - Done
>
> Cards can be moved from left to right with the goal of moving the card to done.  Right now when I move the card to done it basically places it at the bottom of the done column.  I would like it to sort descending so the most recent "done" issue is placed at the top of this column.

That is my question but I'm not sure where I could ask this?

Comment: Maybe [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jira) or [SQA](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jira), keep in mind I just quickly threw these links here. :)

Comment: @bluefeet - When you say just threw these links here...I want to make sure I don't piss people off.  I know how the se community works and asking a question where it doesn't belong is a big sin here...I'd hate to commit it.  How sure are you?

Comment: Well I'm not fully versed on what's on-topic there but they both have jira questions, you could look at and even ask on their meta sites if it would be on-topic.  It was just a "hey, these sites have these questions, maybe they could help" kind of a comment.  Which again is why I commented, instead of answered you.

Comment: Most seem to be asked on StackOverflow but this [search](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=jira+-stackoverflow.com) indicate that besides pm also SuperUser has these kind of questions. My first thought was [webapp.se](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jira) but they only have 11 jira questons.

Comment: Wow there needs to be a site to determine where to ask your question - yes I'm very serious about that!

Comment: JonH, don't hesitate to ask if your question fits on the site itself. Not only can it spark a healthy discussion, but it might actually inspire folks to ask similar questions they never realized could be part of the scope.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I asked here: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/17361/sort-done-jira-agile-column lets hope I don't get stoned to death.  I still think having a site recommend the se site to ask on would be a fun adventure...

Comment: JonH, meta.meta.meta. It's been tried. There's not enough of a problem to build yet another meta site around.

Comment: True but not even knowing what meta site in itself to ask is tough enough.  I guess the solution is ask here!

Comment: @JonH you can ask in both meta sites, that's a valid action. (Asking on two main sites is less valid though)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I know I know but I'd hate too...anyhow let's see how it goes over at pm.  Crossing my fingers...

Comment: Well, that's just taking a risk - better ask in the meta before doing it. No real harm, just risk of people getting frustrated on both sides. (i.e. both you and the users of the site.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I hear ya..I got question happy...I'll change that habit I promise!

Comment: Wow I love this community - http://pm.stackexchange.com/a/17362/22095 God Bless SE!

Answer (score 4):

I decided to post in the project management se site, and sure enough on the same day I got an answer: https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/17362/22095

Love you SE!